# Pandoc: Converting HTML inline styles

Tags: html, latex, pandoc

Pandoc remaps HTML `strong` to LaTeX bold:

```
#  echo "This should be <strong>bold</strong>." | pandoc -f html -t latex
This should be \textbf{bold}.
```

However, my document has inline styles like follows:

```
# echo "This should be <span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">bold</span>." | pandoc -f html -t latex
This should be {bold}.
```

Is it possible to set pandoc to read properly  `<span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">`?

Comment: if you do `pandoc -f html -t native` you see pandoc's internal representation. You could write a [filter](http://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) that transforms this to bold.